# Editing Symbol Position or Size not always Accurate?

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

If I click on a symbol, go to the properties tab, click on the width textbox, type in 1000, hit enter, it then reports the width being 999.95.  That's .05 pixels off from what I wanted.

I have snap to objects disabled.  The symbol in question is a 1000x500 linear gradient rotated 90 degrees alone in it's own layer in a movie clip.

Comment: if i type in 1000.01 it goes to 1000.00, not a great solution though.

Answer (score 0):

yea i have the same problem wtf is that about? flash doesnt respect my authoritay...

-----edit:

wait lol i figured it out! i had to turn off the stroke on the shape i had (mine was actually just a rectangle with which i wanted to make a background same size as whole stage). i guess it was trying to accommodate a 1 pixel wide for the stroke. After i turned off the stroke i was finally able to set the size and position accurately

Comment: No luck for me, my rectangle has no stroke and I still can't get 1000 to be exactly 1000.